# Will this Context object cause unintentional rerenders?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have trouble understanding the "Caveats" section about **unintentional rerender**s when using the **Context API** in React:

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#caveats

Specifically, what do they mean by **"every time the Provider re-renders"**? Does "Provider" here refer to the **App** component in the given example? If yes, does this happen every time a component ***within*** the App component changes? If not, when does the App component ever re-render considering that it's the outer-most component?

In my own code, I wrap all my component inside the `App.tsx` file (or rather `_app.tsx` because I use NextJS) in this context provider:

```
return (
  <TooManyRequestsContext.Provider value={{
    onTooManyRequests: () => setShowTooManyRequestsModal(true),
  }}>

  [...] Components [...]

)
```

Should I **move the context value into a state?**

Comment: If you could include more specific information regarding your current use of `Provider` (namely, how it is updated, some different states it would have, etc), that could help.

Comment: @Rogue The value in my context provider isn't supposed to change. It's just a callback for showing a "too many requests" modal that I want to be able to trigger from many places in my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does "Provider" here refer to the App component in the given example?

Correct. In this case, should `App` be re-rendered (through a prop change or otherwise), the `value` of the `Provider` object consistently gets a new object:

```
<MyContext.Provider value={{something: 'something'}}>
```

The solution suggested on that page (to move the object into the `state` of `App`) is to precisely address the re-creation of the `{something: ...}` object on each call to `#render`.

> If yes, does this happen every time a component within the App component changes?

As specified within the [documentation of React.Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render), a re-render occurs when a component changes its `state` or `props`. That is to say, that if the props or state of a subcomponent within the `App` component update, then `App` will not re-render, but the sub-component that has its props and state changed will.

> Should I move the context value into a state?

In your case, potentially yes. There is not enough clarity surrounding what would be updating the `value` of your Provider. Ideally, this `Provider` would have a concrete value, which may be set by a different component within your tree. Should a change arise in the future such that `App` is no longer top-level, then re-rendering of `App` will start to make this issue "rear its head".

As you are using an anonymous object in your `value`, you are facing directly the issue that is outlined within the "Caveats" section that you linked. If your `App.tsx` file re-renders, then you will have a new object set for that `value`.

Comment: Thank you very much! If I have several `useState` in my App component it means that the App component itself will rerender when I set a new value on any of them, right? From that, I conclude that I should indeed wrap the context provider value into a state.

Comment: However, I never want to change the value inside my context provider. It's just a callback to the App.

Comment: Correct, if you have `useState` within the `App` component, a change in those states will re-render `App`. Thus, moving the context provider into a `state` will prevent the object from changing during those re-renders. To prevent updates to that state, simply don't provide a means of updating it to begin with.